# Find Top 3 Values Per Row and save values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I am trying to find column names of the 3 highest values for each row and save their values.

I found my question was really similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923349/top-3-values-per-row-in-pandas)

However, I don't know how to save the values at the same time.

Like this,

```
| ID | 1st Max    | 2nd Max    | 3rd Max  |
|----|------------|------------|--------- |
| 1  | Var5, 5    | Var4, 4    | Var3, 3  |
| 2  | Var1, 10   | Var2, 9    | Var3, 8  |
| 3  | Var3, 41   | Var2, 37   | Var1, 25 |
| 4  | Var5, 151  | Var1, 102  | Var3, 72 |
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Similar like the question you linked

```
s = df.melt('ID')
s['key'] = s.sort_values('value',ascending=False).groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
s = s[s.key<=3]
s['new'] = s[['variable','value']].astype(str).agg(', '.join,1)
s = s.pivot(index='ID', columns='key', values='new')
Out[22]: 
key          1          2         3
ID                                 
1      Var5, 5    Var4, 4   Var3, 3
2     Var1, 10    Var2, 9   Var3, 8
3     Var3, 41   Var2, 37  Var1, 25
4    Var5, 151  Var1, 102  Var3, 72
```