# How can I get the first three max values from each row in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

The dataframe is like this;

| Cluster | Genre 1 | Genre 2 | Genre 3 | Genre 4 | Genre 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 31 | 5 | 3 | 23 |
| 2 | 53 | 12 | 6 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 44 | 73 | 1 | 9 | 13 |

As output, I want something like this, so I can see what genres are the dominant ones in each cluster.

| Cluster | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Genre 2 | Genre 5 | Genre 1 |
| 2 | Genre 1 | Genre 2 | Genre 4 |
| 3 | Genre 2 | Genre 1 | Genre 5 |

I want to show the top 3 "genres" from each cluster in a graph, I have no idea how I would do this for a row instead of columns. Is anyone here familiar with this?

Comment: send you `dataframe` as text not image

Comment: Why not ```groupby and rank``` and then pick ```head(3)```

Comment: I changed it now to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort` on `df.values` and `axis=1` and select three largest and use df.columns for getting column name:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = df.set_index('Cluster')
res = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-1*df.values,axis=1)[:, :3]], 
                   columns=['1st', '2nd',' 3rd'])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
        1st       2nd       3rd
0   Genre 2   Genre 5   Genre 1
1   Genre 1   Genre 2   Genre 4
2   Genre 2   Genre 1   Genre 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with apply for each row as given in the code below to solve this problem,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> dictA = {'genre1': [10,20,56,2,30,44],'genre2': [ 9,70,96,7,3,54],'genre3': [ 12,10,16,23,39,4],'genre4': [ 40,29,26,15,43,14]}
>>>         
... dfA = pd.DataFrame(dictA)
>>> dfA.index.name = 'cluster'  
>>>     
... dfA.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> 
>>> dfA
   cluster  genre1  genre2  genre3  genre4
0        0      10       9      12      40
1        1      20      70      10      29
2        2      56      96      16      26
3        3       2       7      23      15
4        4      30       3      39      43
5        5      44      54       4      14
>>> df1 = (dfA.set_index('cluster')
...         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nlargest(3).index), axis=1)
...         .reset_index())
>>> df1
   cluster       0       1       2
0        0  genre4  genre3  genre1
1        1  genre2  genre4  genre1
2        2  genre2  genre1  genre4
3        3  genre3  genre4  genre2
4        4  genre4  genre3  genre1
5        5  genre2  genre1  genre4
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923349/top-3-values-per-row-in-pandas)